# Call oracle function with return and output values with Go and go-ora return EOF

Tags: oracle, function, go

In my project they want me to use go-ora as oracle driver, I was using godror and the call was working, but when I changed the driver this occur.

My partial code is this:

```
var newProdId, errMsg string
    var result int


    if _, err := r.db.Exec(callCambioCodmatSap, sql.Out{Dest: &result}, proId, go_ora.Out{Dest: &newProdId, Size: 40}, go_ora.Out{Dest: &errMsg, Size: 200}); err != nil {
        return "", errors.Wrap(err, "error :(")
    }
```

and the call is:

```
callCambioCodmatSap = `BEGIN :result := stl.pa_sinergia_material.f_cambio_codmat_sap(:pin_pro_id, :pout_pro_id, :pout_msj); END;`
```

the error is just "**EOF**" nothing more, nothing less...

The code worked with the other driver. In my original call I did not use the *result* return value, it was not even mapped to an output variable.

The only example that I found in the go-ora examples calling a function only have a return value.